# GLSL textureCube and texture2D in same shader

Tags: opengl, glsl, shader, texture2d, texturing

I can't seem to be able to have both `texture2D()` and `textureCube()` in one shader. When I do, nothing shows up and there is no error. I tried this both with my own shader loader and the Apple GLSL shader builder and the same thing happens. It happens even if I have `textureCube()` in the vertex shader and `texture2D()` in the fragment. They seem to work fine by themselves, but as soon as they're called together, no matter in which order, nothing shows up.

Answer (score 7):

You need to bind both textures as uniforms in both shaders and assign two different texture units, each with one of the textures to the sampler uniforms.