# Bind Texture2D and TextureCube

Tags: c++, directx, shader, hlsl, directx-11

I need to pass both a Texture2D and a TextureCube to my pixel shader at the same time.

I was previously sending an array of texture's but found that I was not able to send a textureCube as well as this.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6027086/glsl-texturecube-and-texture2d-in-same-shader) mentions something called binding but I am unable to find any more information on this and was wondering if someone might be able to point me in direction of a solution for this problem.

Thank you.

Edit----
After attempting to implement Caesar's suggestion the following code causes an error.
First-chance exception when the shader is attempted to be read, the problem line is simply

```
Texture2D texture04 : register( t0 );
```

Which causes a crash after this:

```
D3DX11CompileFromFile("Data/Shaders/Effects.fx", 0, 0, "VS", "vs_4_0", 0, 0, 0, &VS_Buffer, 0, 0);
D3DX11CompileFromFile("Data/Shaders/Effects.fx", 0, 0, "PS", "ps_4_0", 0, 0, 0, &PS_Buffer, 0, 0);
d3dDevice_->CreateVertexShader(VS_Buffer->GetBufferPointer(), VS_Buffer->GetBufferSize(), NULL, &VS);
```

ReEdit----
Rewrote the exact code...worked this time, no idea why. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can register multiple textures in your shader file like so

```
Texture2D texture04 : register( t0 );    
TextureCube myCubeMap : register( t1 );
```

The `t0` and `t1` specify the registry number, and so you use that number as the first parameter for the `PSSetShaderResources`

When you want to set `t0` in your C++ Code you do it like so

```
pImmediateContext->PSSetShaderResources( 0, 1, &(texture) );
```

And when you want to set `t1` you do it like so

```
pImmediateContext->PSSetShaderResources( 1, 1, &(texture) );
```

Comment: The lines to add the register to my pixel shaders are failing. Texture2D texture04 : register( t0 );

Comment: I updated the main post after when I fixed it but forgot to reply to you again / delete the comment above. It's fixed now! Thanks very much for the help.